# What does the reduce(_:_:) function do in Swift?

Tags: swift

Here is a piece of code I don't understand. This code uses swift's reduce(*:*:) function along with the closure which I am having trouble to understand. What are the values set in `maxVerticalPipCount` and `maxHorizontalPipCount`? Are they `5` and `2` respectively?

```
let pipsPerRowForRank = [[0], [1], [1,1], [1,1,1], [2,2], [2,1,2], 
                            [2,2,2], [2,1,2,2], [2,2,2,2], [2,2,1,2,2], 
                            [2,2,2,2,2]]
let maxVerticalPipCount = CGFloat(pipsPerRowForRank.reduce(0) { max($1.count, $0) })
let maxHorizontalPipCount = CGFloat(pipsPerRowForRank.reduce(0) { max($1.max() ?? 0, $0) })
```

Comment: Do you not understand how `reduce` works in general? Or just not understand how it works in this specific case?

Comment: If you run the code, what results do you get? I'm not sure why you are posting a question asking what the results of the code are when you can easily run the code and see for yourself. It's fine to ask for help understanding the code, but not what the final result is.

Comment: https://learnappmaking.com/map-reduce-filter-swift-programming/#reduce

Comment: _Are they 5 and 2 respectively?_ Yes

Comment: I don't understand how this works in this specific case. @Sweeper

Comment: @rmaddy Well this is actually section of the code. I ran it afterwords but I don't understand how the closure is working here properly hence posted this for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, if you’re wondering what precisely `reduce` does, you can always refer to the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/95a15d12bdc01ec392d01fdd6126f68cdd16aa42/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L575), where you can see the actual code as well as a nice narrative description in the comments.

But the root of your question is that this code is not entirely obvious. I might suggest that if you’re finding it hard to reason about the code snippet, you can replace the opaque shorthand argument names, `$0` and `$1`, with meaningful names, e.g.:

```
let verticalMax = pipsPerRowForRank.reduce(0) { previousMax, nextArray in 
    max(nextArray.count, previousMax)
}

let horizontalMax = pipsPerRowForRank.reduce(0) { previousMax, nextArray in
    max(nextArray.max() ?? 0, previousMax)
}
```

By using argument names that make the functional intent more clear, it often is easier to grok what the code is doing. IMHO, especially when there are multiple arguments, using explicit argument names can make it more clear.

---

That having been said, I’d probably not use `reduce` and instead do something like:

```
let verticalMax = pipsPerRowForRank
    .lazy
    .map { $0.count }
    .max() ?? 0
```

To my eye, that makes the intent extremely clear, namely that we’re counting how many items are in each sub-array and returning the maximum count.

Likewise, for the horizontal one:

```
let horizontalMax = pipsPerRowForRank
    .lazy
    .flatMap { $0 }
    .max() ?? 0
```

Again, I think that’s clear that we’re creating a flat array of the values, and then getting the maximum value.

And, in both cases, we’re using [`lazy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689574-lazy) to avoid building interim structures (in case our arrays were very large), but evaluating it as we go along. This improves memory characteristics of the routine and the resulting code is more efficient. Frankly, with an array of arrays this small, `lazy` isn’t needed, but I include it for your reference.

---

Bottom line, the goal with functional patterns is not to write code with the fewest keystrokes possible (as there are more concise renditions we could have written), but rather to write efficient code whose intent is as clear as possible with the least amount of cruft. But we should always be able to glance at the code and reason about it quickly. Sometimes if further optimization is needed, we’ll make a conscious decision to sacrifice readability for performance reasons, but that’s not needed here.

Comment: I didn't write this code. It was written by the teacher who teaches this course. I understood(partially) what it did but had trouble since I felt what the code does could have it been done in a different way. With the suggestions that you mentioned I will keep in my mind while I write code.

Comment: It’s a good skill to know how to read and write those sorts of `reduce` statements, so from a pedagogic perspective, there’s some utility there. But this isn’t the best use-case for `reduce`, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the reduce functions do here

```
var maxVerticalPipCount:CGFloat = 0
for rark in pipsPerRowForRank {
    if CGFloat(rark.count) > maxVerticalPipCount {
        maxVerticalPipCount = CGFloat(rark.count)
    }
}
var maxHorizontalPipCount:CGFloat = 0
for rark in pipsPerRowForRank {
    if CGFloat(rark.max() ?? 0) > maxHorizontalPipCount {
        maxHorizontalPipCount = CGFloat(rark.max() ?? 0)
    }
}
```

You shouldn't use [reduce(*:*:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) function for finding the max value. Use [max(by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2294243-max)
 function like this

```
let maxVerticalPipCount = CGFloat(pipsPerRowForRank.max { $0.count < $1.count }?.count ?? 0)
let maxHorizontalPipCount = CGFloat(pipsPerRowForRank.max { ($0.max() ?? 0) < ($1.max() ?? 0) }?.max() ?? 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reduce function loops over every item in a collection, and combines them into one value. Think of it as literally reducing multiple values to one value. [[Source](https://learnappmaking.com/map-reduce-filter-swift-programming/#reduce)]

From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce)

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let numberSum = numbers.reduce(0, { x, y in
    x + y
})
// numberSum == 10
```

---

In your code,

`maxVerticalPipCount` is iterating through the whole array and finding the max between count of 2nd element and 1st element of each iteration.

`maxHorizontalPipCount` is finding max of 2nd element's max value and first element.

Try to print each element inside reduce function for better understandings.

```
let maxVerticalPipCount = pipsPerRowForRank.reduce(0) {
    print($0)
    return max($1.count, $0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce adds together all the numbers in an array opens a closure and really do whatever you tell it to return.

```
let pipsPerRowForRank = [[1,1], [2,2,2]]
let maxVerticalPipCount = CGFloat(pipsPerRowForRank.reduce(0) { 
                              max($1.count, $0)})
```

Here it starts at `0` at `reduce(0)` and loops through the full array. where it takes the highest value between it's previous value it's in process of calculating and the number of items in the subarray. In the example above the process will be:

```
maxVerticalPipCount = max(2, 0)
maxVerticalPipCount = max(3, 2)
maxVerticalPipCount = 3
```

As for the second one

```
let pipsPerRowForRank = [[1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], []]
let maxHorizontalPipCount = CGFloat(pipsPerRowForRank.reduce(0) { 
                              max($1.max() ?? 0, $0)})
```

Here we instead of checking count of array we check the max value of the nested array, unless it's empty, the it's 0. So here goes this one:

```
let maxHorizontalPipCount = max(2, 0)
let maxHorizontalPipCount = max(3, 2)
let maxHorizontalPipCount = max(4, 3)
let maxHorizontalPipCount = max(0, 4)
let maxHorizontalPipCount = 4
```

Comment: I thought of something as such. Thanks for affirming it.

Answer (score 1):

Example With Swift 5,

```
enum Errors: Error {
    case someError
}

let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
let inititalValue = 0

let sum = numbers.reduce(Result.success(inititalValue)) { (result, value) -> Result<Int, Error> in
    if let initialValue = try? result.get() {
     return .success(value + initialValue)
    } else {
        return .failure(Errors.someError)
    }
}

switch sum {
case .success(let totalSum):
    print(totalSum)
case .failure(let error):
    print(error)
}
```